# SQL Server Locks entire table althrough it isn't needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I am using the following code to delete rows from a SQL Server Table

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) <= 2013
```

and (as the table is large 50GB) while this query is executing I am doing an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(...., CreationDate) VALUES(...., '2014-02-24')
```

(don't mind the date formatting. It's just an example.)

However, the INSERT waits until the DELETE operation is done although, logically, SQL Server could perform the INSERT because it doesn't affect the result of the DELETE operation.

Is there a way to avoid this locking?

Comment: I do not remember the details but there is a threshold beyond which MSSQL decides to lock the whole table. It is an optimization and and the alternative is to lock individual index blocks which would probably be slower.

Answer (score 4):

You could at least try to help the server out by making the search condition SARGable:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE CreationDate < '20140101'
```

Assuming that there is an index on `CreationDate`, it **may** now be able to use that.

Comment: Agree, it's probably having to do a table scan due to the where clause.  Turn on execution plan and see if the delete is doing a table scan.

Comment: That basically is it. NEVER evaluate the filter field - that kills any index used. Sql 101 for larger databases. In this particualr case the transformation is trivial (as you show) and will make sure the index can be used - if naturally it makes sense from a cost thing, which is the decision of the query optimizer.

Comment: I modified the query as you proposed and in fact in the Query Execution Plan it says the query will use the Index. BUT the problem persists: Delete is taking really too much time (maybe because the table many indexes to synchronize) and as the table is locked, no INSERT is being performed.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with something similar to Damien along the lines of...

`Delete From MyTable Where CreationDate='2013'`

`Insert Into MyTable (Creation Date ) Values ( 2014-02-24 ) Where CreationDate=''`

(The '' Would be the records just being deleted before hand I hope )

This will perform the deletion and the insert at the same time , I think you just have syntax errors personally.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the trace and you can find the dead lock situation